# Parallel processing input/output, queries, and indexes AS400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

IBM V6.1

When using the I system navigator and when you click System values the following display.

[image]

By default the `Do not allow parallel processing` is selected.

What will the impact be on processing in programs when you choose multiple processes, we have allot of rpgiv programs and sql queries being executed and  I think it will increase performance?

Basically I want to turn this on in production environment but not sure if I will break anything by doing this for example input or output of different programs running parallel or data getting out of sequence?

I did do some research :

https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzakz/rzakzqqrydegree.htm

And understand each option but I do not know the risk of changing it from default to multiple.

Comment: The impact of parallelism depends mainly on the workload being executed, so the only reliable way to figure out the impact of enabling it is to test it on your workload (you do have a test environment, don't you).

Comment: Yes I do I have a DEV and TEST but the workload is not the same or as much as in production, so I did enable it in DEV and ran SQL but could not see a difference.

Comment: Is there a risk evolved to turn it on in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, in order get the most out of *MAX and *OPTIMIZE, you'd need a system with more than one core (enabled for IBM i / DB2) along with the **DB2 Symmetric Multiprocessing (SMP) (57xx-SS1 option 26)** license program installed; thus allowing the system to use SMP for queries and index builds.

For *IO, the system can use multiple tasks via simultaneous multithreading (SMT) even on a single core POWER 5 or higher box.  SMT is enabled via the *Processor multi tasking (QPRCMLTTSK)* system value

You're unlikely to "break" anything by changing the value.  As long as your applications don't make bad assumptions about result set ordering.  For example, CPYxxxIMPF makes use of SQL behind the scenes;  with anything but *NONE you might end up with the rows in your DB2 table in different order from the rows in the import file.

You will most certainly increase the CPU usage.  This is not a bad thing; unless you're currently pushing 90% + CPU usage regularly.   If you're only using 50% of your CPU, it's probably a good thing to make use of SMT/SMP to provide better response time even if it increases the CPU utilization to 60%.

Having said that, here's a story of it being a problem...  http://archive.midrange.com/midrange-l/200304/msg01338.html

Note that in the above case, the OP was pre-building work tables at sign on in order to minimize the wait when it was time to use them.  Great idea 20 years ago with single threaded systems.  Today, the alternative would be to take advantage of SMP/SMT and build only what's needed when needed.

As you note in a comment, this kind of change is difficult to test in non-production environments since workloads in DEV & TEST are different.  So it's important to collect good performance data before & after the change.  You might also consider moving it stages  *NONE --> *IO --> *OPTIMIZE and then *MAX if you wish.  I'd spend at least a month at each level, if you have periodic month end jobs.